# ASP.Net LINQ to SQL group by syntax for System.Generic.IEnumerable Collection

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, group-by

.Net application calls Stored Procedure and returns collection which is stored as 'result.'  I want to be able to group the results by 'CreatorLineOfBusinessID'.  It returns that field along with several other fields.  I would like to use a LINQ query on the '**result**' data set.  Thanks in advance.

```
Dim result As IEnumerable(Of eRefer_Reports.uspReport_ReferralsSentBetweenLinesOfBusinessResult)

             strFromLOBID = " "
            Session("FromLineOfBusiness") = strFromLOBID
            strToLOBID = " "
            Session("ToLineOfBusiness") = strToLOBID

            result = repository.GetQueryResults(CDate(Me.txtStartDate.Text), CDate(Me.txtEndDate.Text), strFromLOBID, strToLOBID)
            BindGridView(result)
```

Comment: As `Lcarus` has pointed out you do not need to use LINQ to do this grouping. Because your result is already `IEnumerable<uspReport_ReferralsSentBetweenLinesOfBusinessResult>` you can use the GroupBy method as well.

Comment: @Susan How did you go? Were you able to get the report to group?

Comment: Sorry, it's been awhile but been on vacation.  I'm struggling with the syntax. I was trying:  BindGridView(result.GroupBy(CreatorLineOfBusinessID)), but this doesn't work.  Sorry for being such a newbie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim query = result.GroupBy(Function(x) x.ID).ToList()
```

Should group the results the way you want.

Comment: Not being picky but she did say "LINQ query". :D Otherwise yeah I would just use this `Enumerable.GroupBy(Of TSource, TKey)` as well.

Comment: @JeremyChild: Yep, you are right. In that case, Jeremy's answer is what she's looking for.

Comment: @Lcarus But its the same thing :D LINQ To Objects would no doubt use IEnumerable.GroupBy without you realizing it. Using the GroupBy method  makes for cleaner code.

Comment: Dim xyz = result.GroupBy(Function(x) x.CreatorLineOfBusinessName)
BindGridView(xyz)  The BindGridView command is giving me an error saying that result cannot be converted to Systems.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of eRefer_Reports.usp_ReferralsSentBetweenBusinessLinesResult as required for the 'out' generic parameter 'T' in interface IEnunerable(Of OUt T)

Comment: @Susan: Try calling ToList() at the end; which should return List(Of usp_ReferralsSentBetweenBusinessLinesResult) and you should be able to bind to your gridview

Answer (score 2):

Have you done any research on Linq grouping? Try the 101 examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688088

```
Dim orderGroups = From p In results Group p By Key = p.CreatorLineOfBusinessID Into Group _
Select CreatorBusinessId = Key, Referrals = Group
```

Then just iterate over `orderGroups` using the Key and the property Referrals which will be an `IEnumerable<eRefer_Reports.uspReport_ReferralsSentBetweenLinesOfBusinessResult>`

```
For Each lobBusiness in orderGroups

 ' Get the lobBusinessId : .CreatorBusinessId
 ' Get the IEnumerable results: .Referrals

Next
```